# Makefile doesn't recompile if not make clean

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

```
#use g++ for everything
CC= g++

# include debugging symbols in object files,
# and enable all warnings
FLAGS= -g -Wall -std=c++11

BSTHPP= BST.hpp BSTNode.hpp BSTIterator.hpp

all: main

bst: testBST.o $(BSTHPP)
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o bst testBST.o $(BSTHPP)

main: main.o $(BSTHPP)
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o main main.o $(BSTHPP)

main.o: $(BSTHPP)
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c main.cpp

testBST.o: testBST.cpp
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c testBST.cpp

clean:
        $(RM) main bst *.o
```

I changed the BST.hpp file and then run `make bst`. But I debug for several times and find out firstly I need to `make clean`, then recompile. But why? Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Look into the `-MD` option and `include *.d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `.o` files that need to depend on the `.hpp`, not the executable (which should also not mention them in its recipe).

Comment: Hi, I just update the Makefile. Do you think this time, change in BST.hpp will make it recompile?

Comment: @Chen: Don't edit the question out of your question.  It looks closer, but there are several extra `$(BSTHPP)`s still.

Comment: Actually, this is the one that has problems. So why executable depend on hpp will make it stop recompiling?

Comment: @Chen: When you keep your `.o` files, having the executable depend on anything else is useless.